# Restricting App download based on screen size (Android - Titanium Studio)

Tags: android, titanium

I have created an application in iPhone and it works fine as the screen size of all iPhones are same.

Now i have created the same application for Android using Titanium studio.

The app works fine in Galaxy S3 (and Nexus 7), but my concern is what if i would like to restrict other Android devices from using my app?

How do i do this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Note :** Screen sizes i use in emulator `WXGA720` and `WVGA800`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the manifest (only add the compatible screens that you want):

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Should I do this in tiapp.xml or in actual manifest file? If in actual manifest file, is there any format that I sould follow. Thanks.

Comment: ProyectFolder\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks you.. +1 for the answer.
Can you suggest what should i use to enable only Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7 and disable all other devices?

Comment: I think you can not. At least, I don't know how

Comment: You can put this into tiapp.xml: http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-custom-androidmanifest